Inclusion in a set using formal logic
I am having trouble understanding the definition of a subset in terms of formal logic, I want to prove that these statements are logically equivalent:
Let $A,B$ be subsets of $E$
$$
A\cap B = \emptyset \\
\equiv \\
A\subset (B\cap \bar{A}) \\
\equiv \\
B\subset (A\cap \bar{B})  
$$
Here is my question:
Take $A\subset (B\cap \bar{A})$, this is logically equivalent to saying:
$$\forall x, x\in A \implies x \in B\cap \bar{A}\\
\equiv \\
\forall x, x\in A \implies x \in B \wedge x \notin A\\
$$
But is this equivalent to:
$$\forall x, x\notin A \vee (x \in B \wedge x \notin A)
$$
or is it equivalent to:
$$\exists x, x\notin A \vee  (x \in B \wedge x \notin A)
$$
As in, do the existential and universal quantifiers that act on the WHOLE statement switch when one part is negated?
Edit:
I just thought that maybe the two ones I proposed are wrong and instead, this one is correct: (?)
$$\exists x, x\notin A \vee (\forall x, x \in B \wedge x \notin A)
$$

$$A\subset (B\cap \bar{A})$$ is (mathematically) equivalent to $$\forall x;\big( x\in A \Longrightarrow x \in B \wedge x \notin A\big), $$ which is logically equivalent to $$\forall x;\big(  x\notin A ,\vee, (x \in B \wedge x \notin A\big).$$

FWI those statements are certainly NOT equivilent.  $A\cap B=\emptyset$ only means that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint.  $A={1,2}$ and $B= {3,4}$ can be an example of that.  $A\subset(B\cap \overline A)$ however can only be true if $A$ is empty. (As you have shown every element of $A$ must be not in $A$ and the only way that can happen is if $A$ is empty.)  By the exact same reasoning 3) is true only if $B$ is empty.  To try to prove these are equivalent is going to destroy the universe.  You don't want to do that.

The three statements that you want to prove are equivalent are not in fact equivalent.  The second is equivalent to $A=\emptyset$, and the third is equivalent to $B=\emptyset$.
To see this, notice that $B\cap\overline A$ is a subset of $\overline A$. So the second of your three statements implies that $A\subseteq\overline A$. And the only set that does this is $A=\emptyset$. In (even more) detail, we have $A=A\cap A\subseteq A \cap\overline A=\emptyset$.
Similarly, your third statement is equivalent to $B=\emptyset$. And not two of the three statements are generally equivalent to each other.
